# Dockerfile and iptables command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to add `iptables` command to my `Dockerfile`, but fails to do so.

Here my attempt so far:

```
RUN iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 8884
```

I've also tried:

```
CMD ["iptables", "-t", "nat", "-A", "PREROUTING", "-p", "tcp", "-j", "REDIRECT", "--to-port", "8884"]
```

But also fails. What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  I'd broadly assume tweaking firewall rules is something you can't do in Docker (and definitely can't do in a Dockerfile; images don't persist any sort of side effects beyond their filesystems).

Comment: A Docker container doesn't have a kernel with netfilter capabilities, the only way to filter packets is through the host's netfilter kernel module. If you want to redirect packets to your container you should publish your application network ports so that docker knows what to do with them.

Comment: The command does work when I call it in the Docker after "boot".